# Share the App email send from PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-intent, preference

I am trying to create a feature in my Android App which will let users share the link to my app in android market to whoever they want to email it to.

In `preferences.xml` I have created this as below

```
<PreferenceScreen
            android:title="Share the App" 
            android:summary="Share the App with your friends.">

        <intent android:action="" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I am not sure what intent should I put here and how I do I handle it when Share the App is clicked in `PreferenceScreen`. I want to open Email and pre-populate it with a subject and the Android Market link of the App in the subject.

The user will enter the email and send it to their friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did and it worked.

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen
            android:title="Share the App" 
            android:summary="Share the App with your Friends.">

        <intent android:action="myapp.action.SHARE_APP" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Then I added this to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".ShareApp"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="myapp.action.SHARE_APP" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>                      
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then I created a ShareApp.java and added the code here.

```
public class ShareApp extends UrSettings {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey there! Cheers!");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Try MyApp!"); 
        startActivity(emailIntent);  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And it worked!! By the way the UrSettings class is extended from PreferenceActivity.

Comment: Presumably you want to include a market url to the app in the EXTRA_TEXT body?